# Overriding an id

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a project with three other programmers (two of which are more advanced than me), so simply changing the structure/names is not really a workable solution.

We have an id called `head_subhead`, with some styles applied to it.

All of the pages used this template (it is in Drupal), and thus all pages have `head_subhead` in the structure.

I would like to, for a specific page(s) override `#head_subhead`.

I would like to do this without adding an id to the page body, or higher element. Could I do this by adding an additional class? Could I use the class already applied to the page body (i.e., .pagename #head_subhead) or would that be useless?

What's the most efficient way to override #head_subhead, without using `!important`

Answer (score 3):

> Could I use the class already applied to the page body

Yes you could, if you're only targeting that page.

```
.page_body_class #head_subhead { /* CSS */ }
```

You could also target parent divs if they are unique to the page/pages you want the css to affect.

```
.some_parent_div_class #head_subhead { /* CSS */ }
```

But if you're going to use this often, just add a class to the head_subhead element.

```
#head_subhead.extra_class { /* CSS */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `!important` to override your styles, you will find it difficult to handle your stylesheet, using `id`, your selector will have higher preference compared to `class`. If you want to override the `id`, use more specific selector like

```
#head_subhead .class p {
   styles here
}
```

Assign the `class` to your element you want to select, you can keep adding more and more elements, classes or ids just to make your selector more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you must use a greater specificity. You can do this by having the overridden css selector be called after the original one, whether it's further down the same file (why), or within a separate file that's included after the original css selector is created.

Alternately, you can create greater specificity by using additional selectors, such as a descendant selector like: `.superclass #id`. You could put a special class on the body of the page you need the special style on, and use that as the `.superclass` part of that selector, for instance.

Really though, this is why I do not use ids at all within my css code. Using classes everywhere is a much better solution (I know you said this isn't feasible for your situation, just giving my 2 cent opinion on the topic).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class won't do the trick ID is of higher priority. You can even see that https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info here.

Without using anything there will be only one answer, remove the id! Other methods are already being denied by you! Such as `!IMPORTANT`, adding ID or class to parent. Then remove the id to prevent it. Or atleast use this

```
<element id="@if(condition == true) {<text>head_subhead</text>}"></element>
```

Apply the if else block to only show the id when some condition is true; which in your case means to be shown only in specific pages.

I am sorry I used ASP.NET code, you can yourself change the code type to your own. And you'll get rid of the id where it is not required!